# How spark writing works with S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I'm trying to understand, How spark framework interacts with AWS's s3 service to write into ?

what I can understand is, S3 is storage service from AWS and its exposed as API (eg `s3://s3bucket-path-folder/`) and we use this api (`location of s3 bucket`) in our spark code to write our data.

Since s3 path works as a API and if we are using it in our spark code to write our data, here I'm confused. Does spark framework already have aws api integration (s3 bucket) to write data into it ? Because I think, to interact with API http methods and some parameters also required.

Can anyone please help me to clear this confusion ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, spark has native integration to write to S3. You don't need to do anything to enable spark integration with S3. Just a simple`spark.write.parquet("s3/path/")` will be able to write the data to S3.

Comment: How we can delete data from s3 folder (if exists) using spark code before writing ?

Comment: @Maria, add mode("overwrite"). It will overwrite the underlying data with the new data in S3.

Comment: @ms12, then why its being said that spark doesnt support s3 delete, if overwrite doing the same thing ?

Comment: @Maria delete != overwrite. For example, if you partition your data by date and you reprocess the data for already existing dates, it will rewrite those partitions in S3. It will not delete the partition and only then write the data.